# How to unpack archives on double click?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, zip, archiving

On macOS, double clicking a zip archive immediately unpacks it into a folder with the same name and then opens the folder. There are [third party](https://theunarchiver.com/) apps that do the same for other types of archives as well.

How can I achieve the same behavior on Windows 10? I didn't find any option like this in all the archive software that I tried. I rarely, if ever, want to modify an existing archive or just look into the contents without unpacking. 99% of the time when I'm dealing with an archive I want to either create one or unarchive one.

Comment: Which unarchive parameters: Unarchive where? Create a sub-folder or not? etc.

Comment: It looks like there's a solution which you can adapt, here: https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/27677919/7-zip-change-to-extract-on-double-click.html